# How to subscribe to the mailpoet2 list when saving custom post type?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have custom post type which has custom field type email. I want to submit the email field value to the subscribers' list with ID 4 when saving the post.

```
function save_employees_post($post_id, $post){
  if(get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'employees'){
        //you could make some validation even though validation
    //is also processed in our function
    $my_email_variable = $_POST['acf[field_5a1f1c5c4ff35]'] ;
    $my_list_id1 = $_POST['4'];

    //in this array firstname and lastname are optional
    $user_data = array(
        'email' => $my_email_variable);

    $data_subscriber = array(
      'user' => $user_data,
      'user_list' => array('list_ids' => array($my_list_id1))
    );

    $helper_user = WYSIJA::get('user','helper');
    $helper_user->addSubscriber($data_subscriber);
    //this function will add the subscriber to mailpoet


    }
}

add_action('save_post', 'save_employees_post', 10, 2);
```

The function is not giving any result. How can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution for the problem.

```
function my_project_updated_send_email( $post_id, $post, $update ) { 
// If this is just a revision, don't send the email. 
if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) 
    return; 

$post_type = get_post_type($post_id); 

// If this isn't a 'employees' post, don't update it. 
if ( "employees" != $post_type ) return; 

if ($post->post_status == 'publish' && $update){ 

    $value = get_field('email', $post_id);

    // make sure and check name of field or if is acf field 
    $list_ids = array( 1,4 ); 

    // check name of field or if is acf field 
    if ($value) { //in this array firstname and lastname are optional 
        $user_data = array( 
            'email' => $value); 

    $data_subscriber = array( 
        'user' => $user_data, 
        'user_list' => array('list_ids' => array($list_ids)) ); 

    $helper_user = WYSIJA::get('user','helper'); 
    $helper_user->addSubscriber($data_subscriber); 

    } 
}
```

}

add_action( 'save_post', 'my_project_updated_send_email', 30, 3 );